# How can I make gradle overwrite the library in my local maven repo?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, repository

I have three android projects under current development - let's call them Alpha, Bravo, and Charlie. Bravo and Charlie both depend on Alpha, an android library. When I create Alpha, I deploy it to my local maven repository using `./gradlew install`, which works fine if I use the following in my `build.gradle` files for Bravo and Charlie:

```
dependencies {
      compile 'com.blah.alpha:alpha:1.1.0+@aar'
}
```

The catch, though, is that all three projects are under development. Thus, when I make an update to Alpha and deploy it to my local Maven repository, Bravo and Charlie don't seem to see the local version unless I do the following:

```
$ cd ~/.m2/repository/com/blah/alpha/
$ rm -rf 1.1.0
$ cd -
$ ./gradlew install
```

That is, I manually need to go through and clean my local Maven repository before deploying to it. The version number isn't changing, so I'm wondering if that's the reason it's not getting the most recent build of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That static version is part of it. You could change your version to `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` which Gradle considers a "changing" module. However, Gradle will still only redownload the artifact every 24 hours by default. You can override this behavior and instruct Gradle not to cache changing modules at all. More info can be found in the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:controlling_caching).

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

<strike>If you are not willing to change your artifact version you could try using [`ResolutionRules`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/cache/ResolutionRules.html).</strike>

**Edit:** You can tell Gradle your dependency is a changing dependency.

```
compile('com.blah.alpha:alpha:1.1.0+@aar') {
    changing true
}
```